Read Velocity direction Staubli
I want to read Satubli arm velocity in mm/s, I am using getSpeed(flange) to read flange velocity, but that function gives me only value of velocity, no direction (+ or -). How could I know the directio of robot movement?

The Standard VAL 3 programming language has the getSpeed() instruction you are using, but as you noted it gives speed, but not direction. The Standard VAL 3 language does not have an instruction to do this.
However the Standard VAL 3 language can be extended by using software add ons. The add ons are best though of as beta instructions. Staubli uses them to test new features to see if they work and if users find them them useful. The most common software add on is the "expansion" add on. In it there is a variation of the getSpeed instruction called "$getSpeedCmd(tool tTool, frame fFrame, num x_nCartSpeed[] )" that returns the velocity in X, Y, Z, RX, RY, and RZ by setting the 6 values into the numeric  array x_nCartSpeed.
You will need to contact the Staubli business unit that covers your location and ask for a copy of the expansion add on. They will need to know the Staubli Robotics Control (SRC) software version running on your robot controller. Each software add is version specific as they have to be recompiled with each new SRC release.

Thanks Jim. I have installed expansion.exe in Controller>usr>app. When I use aioSet(aSpeed,$getSpeedCmd(tTool1))function and transfer to controller, it says that $getSpeedCmd() is undefined function. I dont know whats is going wrong...
In usr>app I have expansion.dll and expansion.so

The expansion.so goes in the controller, usr/app/ folder. Check the the robot/information page for Expansion version to make sure it installed. the dll file is added to the emulator used in SRS by running the expansion.exe program.

I am able to use that function. But I follow reading robot speed in absolute value using $getSpeedCmd(tTool1). I am trying to use num $getSpeedCmd(tool tTool, frame fFrame, num& nX, num& nY, num& nZ, num& nRx, num& nRy, num& nRz) function it says invalid parameters. I do not unsderstand how to use that function. How does it save the six values in a AIO?

it updates 6 numbers, not AIOs. In example the 'num&' is a reference to a num variable. if you want to output them to an analog out, you would have to use aioSet on each num variable.

I am using the following function: $getSpeedCmd(tTool1,world,nX,nY,nZ,nRx,nRy,nRz), where 6 parameters are num type I have defined. I have error of invalid parameters. Why?

What is the SRC (VAL 3) version that you are using? The add on for each version can be different.

I am using s8.15.3-Cs9_BS3337.

Ok the documentation does not match the implementation for this SRC version. You need '$getSpeedCmd(tool, frame, nArray)' where nArray is a array of 6 num values instead of 6 separate num variables.

It works. Your help has been very useful Jim. Thank you very much, truly
